# Is com.apple.madrid.plist a suspicious plist?

Tags: plist

I have a Plist called

```
com.apple.madrid.plist
```

in `~/Library/Preferences`

that was updated just yesterday (not by me)

[image: plist]

I do not use FaceTime, iMessages.

**What is it ?**

I lived in Spain for a while and visited Madrid, but that can not be it :)

OS 10.13.6

Comment: I believe the ...madrid.plist file used to have something to do with iMessage and/or FaceTime. BTW/ What version of macOS are you running on your Mac?

Comment: 10.13.6 and I do not use iMessage nor Face Time

Answer (score 2):

> "Madrid" was the internal codename for iMessage before the iMessage product name was used.

The above is from [@pytey on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pytey/status/127644352091664384). You can find many references to Madrid within iMessage, many of which are detailed in [Messages on theiphonewiki.com](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Messages).

Even if you don't use iMessage, the plist still exists as part of iCloud communication. It stores simple metadata, mostly around syncing and CloudKit per the keys in the file.

Comment: can I delete it or just let it be

Comment: @Buscar I guess you can delete it (deleting it is regarded as a support step for people having difficulty with iMessage connectivity according to some quick Googling) but since the file is being written to per the modification date, I suppose it would come straight back next time macOS wanted to write a preference.

Comment: is there a way to find out who is writing the Plist

Comment: @Buscar `sudo opensnoop -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.madrid.plist` to watch process accesses

Comment: dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available  ... and this... dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 6 (ID 949: syscall::open_nocancel:return): invalid user access in predicate at DIF offset 152